# the English Language Teacher

Tags: grammar

I was taught that with the word language, the definite article is used.

> 1. *The English language* versus *English*
> 2. *The English language Teacher* versus  *English teacher*

What are article usage rules for '*a/the English Language teacher*'?

Comment: Suggested migration to [ell.se] **if** found suitable.

Comment: *The English Language teacher* is incorrectly capitalized but grammatical. *The English language teacher* is grammatical and capitalized correctly. *An English language teacher* is grammatical as well. *English language teacher* without an article is grammatical. *The English language* is grammatical. *An English language* is grammatical. *English language* with no article is grammatical. They just all mean different things. This is like asking if *cat* or *dog* is correct. Both are equally correct, but you use them in different circumstances, for different reasons, and to a different effect.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Whilst the linked to question has some very good answers, it isn't sufficient for answering the needs of this question .... So, I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: @Kris, RegDwight - is this question really duplicate? There is a separate article usage rule for 'the ______ language' case, which is not contained in the earlier answer on the topic. So, if a person does not know the rule he or she may not be able to ask a precise question.

Comment: @javaNoobs I'm not the one who said it's a dupe (though the closure box attributes it to me). This belongs to [ELL.SE] I said.

Answer (score 1):

In case of 'The English language teacher', '**the**' refers to '**teacher**', and 'English language' is an adjective. Consider these examples:

> I am **a teacher**.
>
> -What subject do you teach?
>
> -I am **an** English language **teacher**.

You can rephrase the last sentence in this way:

> I am **a teacher** of **the English language**

Another example, [Cambridge University](http://www.cambridge.org/us/cambridgeenglish/catalog/grammar-vocabulary-and-pronunciation/grammar-english-language-teachers-2nd-edition) published

> '**Grammar for English Language Teachers**', not 'the English Language Teachers'.

Comment: "Grammar for the English Language Teacher." :)